# Clarification on a concept involving Hall subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $H\leq G$. If $Q \in$ Hall$_{\pi}(G)$ such that $Q \cap H \in$ Hall$_{\pi}(H)$. Is true that $Q \leq H$ when Hall$_\pi(H)$ $\subseteq$ Hall$_\pi(G)$

Comment: Yes clearly, because that implies $Q \cap H \in {\rm Hall}_\pi(G)$.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is it always true that Hall$_\pi(H)$ $\subseteq$ Hall$_\pi(G)$ for any subgroup $H$ or does $H$ have to be normal?

Comment: ${\rm Hall}_\pi(H) \subseteq {\rm Hall}_\pi(G)$ if and only if $|G|/|H|$ is not divisible by any prime in $\pi$. Did you mean something else perhaps?

Comment: Would it also hold if a Hall system $\Sigma$ of $G$ reduces into $H$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.